# WP7 - Xaml Pages and Peak Memory problem

Tags: windows-phone-7, memory-management, garbage

I have a problem with 90mb peak memory limit issue.

For example: I create 1 Panorama Application(with default content) and add 3 PivotPages or 6 Portrait Page(Page A and Page B.. with blank content). Each time I navigate and go back between these pages the memory usage is going higher and higher. At the end, It passes the 90mb limit.

I use buttons to navigate like this:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PageA.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Do I miss something important while navigating between pages? While searching for a solution I heard about garbage collector? How can I use it or do I need to?

I couldn't find an answer for that; I found this similar topic: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/76007/466968.aspx but there isn't a final solution.

Note: I am using Coding4fun toolkit to measure memory usage.

---

Edit: I created a sample panorama application with some pivot pages (1 with content).

http://i54.tinypic.com/zfip.jpg

At start, application opened with 30mb. After I navigate to the same pivot page a couple of times, Peakmemory started to increase little by little and stoped at 47mb. Is this normal? Maybe, I didn't understand the dynamics of this application building stuff. But it doesn't make sense if it keeps increasing the ram usage and makes application crush after some use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somethign is stopping your pages from being unloaded when you navigate away from them. You probably have a resource leak somewhere but without seeing your code we will be very unlikely to be able to help more.

You shouldn't need to worry about garbage collection.

Comment: Hi Lacey, thanks for your response. I added one silly sample :) with really basic content but peakmemory usage is still increasing. Is this normal? Shall I turn to using Portrait pages.

Comment: @FrankCap the orientation of the page will not be affecting this. You're probably registerting event handlers in the pages and not removing them later. That or you're downloading lots of images frmo the web and not releasing the resources manually.

Comment: Sorry Mybad, what I mean with PortraitPage is simple PhonePage. Btw, In the sample I used local image and textblock. Is there any guide or way for me to learn how to release resources? Thank you very much for your help